# Use SQL parameter to filter multiple comboboxes in vb.net

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, sqlparameter

How can I filter multiple combo boxes value in vb.net with SQL server query? All the comboboxes are user input.
Example:

I have cboName.text, cboAge.text, cboAddress.text

```
SELECT name, age, address
FROM tbMaster 
WHERE name = '" & cboName.text & "'
AND age = '" & cboAge.text & "'
AND address = '" & cboAddress.text & "'
```

If cboName is empty then it will display all Name.

What I did is:

```
IF cboName.text  = '' AND cboAge.text = '' THEN
    SELECT name,age,address FROM tbMaster

ELSEIFcboName.text <> '' AND cboAge.text = '' THEN
    SELECT name,age,address FROM tbMaster WHERE name = '" & cboName.text & "'

ELSEIF cboName.text  = '' AND cboAge.text <> '' THEN
    SELECT name,age,address FROM tbMaster WHERE age = '" & cboAge.text & "'

ELSEIFcboName.text <> '' AND cboAge.text <> '' THEN
    SELECT name,age,address FROM tbMaster WHERE name = '" & cboName.text & "' AND age = '" & cboAge.text & "'
```

and so on...
Imagine if I have to filter 10 comboboxes.

How can I do it with SQL parameter effectively?

Thanks.

Comment: FYI, that code is *wide* open to injecting  attacks. Always, *always, **always*** parametrise your code. [Why do we always prefer using parameters in SQL statements?](//stackoverflow.com/q/7505808)

Comment: It seems that what you want is a "[kitchen sink](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/backtobasics-updated-kitchen-sink-example)" or "[catch-all](https://www.sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2009/03/19/catch-all-queries/)" query

Comment: Yeah i know. That's why i asked how to solve it. Thnaks.